# How to check if conditions are met in consecutive days (in R)

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I am fairly new to R and I am trying to identify the locations which meet two criteria

1. The two previous days have a minimum number of items sold of 7 or more
2. The two previous days have at least three hours of items sold of 80 or more

This is to be displayed in a shiny app in which days these two criteria are met.

I thought of using data.table:

```
group_by(group = data.table::rleid(items_sold < 80),
                         group1 = cumsum(date_time - lag(date_time, default = first(date_time)) > 3600))
```

But this looks to consecutive hours........
I am completely lost, any help will be very welcome!

my dataset:
[My_dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2e9q.png)

Comment: Please don't share data as images. Use `dput(df)` and paste the output here.

Comment: Don't quite understand the question, but you can use 'difftime' to get the number of days between two dates. Just `difftime(some_date, some_other_date, units = "days")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use packages `lubridate` and `dplyr` to group hours by day

This should work if you replace `your_data` with whatever you've called your data.

Are you your conditions are correct? Feels like it should be 80 items sold over two days and at least three hours in which over 7 sales are made?

Note that your problem is a little ambiguous - I've treated it as 'a total of *n* sales over two days', rather than 'at least *n* sales per day for two days'. If you want the latter, you'll need to tweak this code.

The `%>%` operator here is a *pipe* - it takes whatever precedes it and makes it the first argument of the next function. So `x %>% f(y = 2)` is equivalent to `f(x, y = 2)`

```r
# You'll need these packages
require(dplyr)
require(lubridate)

### Creating a 'daily sales' column
 your_data %>%
   ## Group the hours into days w/ lubridate::ymd()
   group_by(lubridate::ymd(date_time)) %>%
   ## Create two new columns: items sold per day, and total hours
   ## in the day that sales exceeded 80
   mutate(sales_today = sum(items_sold),
          hours_exceeding = sum(items_sold >= 80)) %>% 
   # ungroup and overwrite
   ungroup -> your_data 

### Get columns for previous two days
 your_data %>% 
   group_by(lubridate::ymd(date_time)) %>% # still 'thinking in days'
   ## 'shift' existing columns to compare each day with previous two
   mutate(sales_yesterday = lag(sales_today, n = 1),
          sales_day_before = lag(sales_today, n = 2),
          hours_exceeding_yesterday = lag(hours_exceeding, n = 1),
          hours_exceeding_day_before = lag(hours_exceeding, n = 2)
          ) %>% 
   ## Use new columns to get totals for previous two days
   mutate(sales_last_two_days =
            sales_yesterday + sales_day_before,
          hours_exceeding_last_two_days =
            hours_exceeding_yesterday + hours_exceeding_day_before) %>% 
   ## Drop unwanted columns
   select(-sales_yesterday, -sales_day_before,
          -hours_exceeding_yesterday, -hours_exceeding_day_before) %>%  
   ## Create a logical which indicates that the criteria are met
   mutate(meets_criteria = 
            hours_exceeding_last_two_days >= 3 &
            sales_last_two_days >= 7) %>% 
   ungroup -> your_data
```

Comment: Hi @Captain Hat, Thanks for your brilliant answer. It has given me some good ideas.
I should have formulated the 2nd point better, what what I meant was "Checking if in 2 consecutive days, there have been at least 3 hours in which more than 80 items were sold" - I will try to see if I can get there from your answer :)